# Copy files from several Windows nodes to a single Linux host

Tags: ansible

I am trying to copy several files from windows nodes (Node A and Node B) into a linux node were ansible is (Node C).

My question is, there is a way to copy files directly from windows nodes to a linux node, if yes, how for this situation?

The only workaround that I have think about is using a remote shared folder, were all the nodes had access to write in it, and use **win_copy** for windows nodes to that location and after that a **copy** for the linux node to pick those files.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I've just notice that the right module for this task is fetch, it also works on Windows Nodes. Its a reverse command compared with copy modules.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/fetch_module.html